# UWP C# - Re-launch app from notification click

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a UWP app, and I have a ScheduledToastNotification that is added to the schedule when the app is suspended (e.g. like a reminder). However, if I close the app, the notification appears on time, but when I click on the notification (no buttons, just on the notification in general), the app doesn't launch correctly, stopping at the splash screen.

How do I get the app the re-launch correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it and check what happens when you launch app from reminder? You can do that with desktop app by going to Debug -> Other Debug Targets -> Debug Installed App Package, then choose your app and check "Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts" and press Start. After that launch the app from reminder and debug it.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. But just to clarify, when a notification is clicked on, the app is supposed to launch correctly without any extra event handlers like OnLaunched or anything, right?

Comment: Yes, but there could arise any problems with other launching methods like secondary tiles, notifications, etc. Especially if you have any additional code in App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override `OnActivated` in `App.Xaml.cs` and handle this like

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
            {
                var toastArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;
                var arguments = toastArgs.Argument;

                if (arguments == "ARG")
                {
                    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                    if (rootFrame == null)
                    {
                        rootFrame = new Frame();
                        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                    }
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YOURPAGE));
                    Window.Current.Activate();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the app being launched/activated? I mean, I want the notification to dismiss and not open the app.

Comment: Check the app Notifications from Microsoft, where a lot of samples are demonstrated. I think that you are looking for activation types -> background with app closed.

Comment: I found the answer. It's a change to the xml. Nothing to do with activation. And it makes sense since I don't want it to be activated in the first place. But thanks.

Comment: how to do this for a js app?

Comment: I tried to add "system" and "Background" to the <toast launch="..."> but the app is still opens when i click the notification.OnActivated is being called instead of OnBackgroundActiviated