# Adding code to a Toast Notification UWP

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, uwp, toast

I've a Toast notification that execute from outside the project (In a background one). Here you have:

```
private void SendMessage(string title, string text)
{
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
    XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(title));
    textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(text));
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));
}
```

My problem is when I try to execute code when the user click the toast, I want to execute part of the code form the Main project. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer, is similar to your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636189/uwp-c-sharp-re-launch-app-from-notification-click/37653176#37653176

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/) you can find section *Handling activation from a toast notification*
Shortly:
after toast clicked OnActivated event invoked and you can check arguments.
Using new toast template:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
  {

  }
}
```

and using old template (like I think you have):

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   string launchString = args.Arguments
   // ....
}
```